# How to make an onEdit simple trigger work on all sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Is there a way to apply it to each sheet?

```
function onEdit(e){ 
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value != "FALSE") return; 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1").hideRows(e.range.rowStart, 5); 
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1")` with `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` to hide rows in the current sheet instead of always hiding rows in `sheet1`.